# What CSS can replace an <img> tag with a <div> and have same placement behavior

Tags: html, css, image

I have the following markup:

https://jsfiddle.net/charleso/v66afdpx/

html:

```
<p class="title">
   <img class="logo" src="images/logo-A.png" /><span>Log in</span>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
<link href="css/style-A.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I have the same structure repeated for two more themes: `style-B.css` and `style-C.css`

Each has a different logo image and color set. Changing the color set is easy, how can we change change the logo image used in each theme?

In effect, how can I replace the :

```
<img class="logo" src="images/logo-A.png" /><span>Log in</span>
```

with:

```
<div class="logo"></div><span>Log in</span>
```

and have the same alignment I had with the span?

Or, IS there a better way to achieve the same goal?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a JS Fiddle or something that can provide a minimum reproducible example?  Its hard to provide an answer that produces the same span alignment when we can't see what your CSS is doing.

Comment: I have added a js fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default alignement of an image is:

```
 display: inline;
```

Just add this property to your .logo div!

Also, you can change the image by setting right width and height, plus adding the right background-image this way:

```
.logo {
    min-height: 60px;
    min-width: 60px;
    background: url(../images/logo-A.png)no-repeat center center;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please is there anyway to address the concern that "company logo image should be represented with an IMG tag at least once, so the user can save it as file"

Comment: It is the background position. So if you want your image to appear at the center of your height and center of your width, In this case, if you put the exact height and width it will not have a huge effect. But, if you would put the background image on a larger div, you could set the position this way.

Comment: Have you put the width and the height of your image file?

Comment: Sorry, use display: inline-block instead

Comment: Not usually, doing this code with the right path you should be fine... are you sure that your path is okay?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104646/discussion-between-charleso-and-yann-chabot).

Answer (score 1):

Create a DIV which will pretend an image, but stepping back to web-design fundamentals your company logo image should be represented with an IMG tag at least once, so the user can save it as file.

```
<div>
    <div class="image">
    </div>
    <span>Your Span</span>
</div>

.image {
    background: url('path/to/your/image.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: //your image width
    height: //your image height 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hy, i don't have understand very well, have you just try with

```
.logo{    
background-image:url("../logo.png")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using css:

```
.logo {
  background: url("images/logo-A.png");
  display: inline;
  width: //some width;
  height: //some height;
}
```

Comment: Without width and height the .logo width will have 0px height and width so he will not appear

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into using CSS [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) property or it's parent / shorthand, the [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/background) property.

This allows you to set an image url which will be used as the background for an image. This is perfect for swapping out theme-specific icons as you don't have to change **any** HTML whatsoever and since changing a logo is technically part of the presentational layer it should belong in CSS too.

What you could then do is give your logo container a fixed width and height, e.g.

**main.css**

```
.logo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-size: cover; // choose what fits here
    background-position: center; // choose what fits here
}
```

**style-a.css**

```
.logo {
    background-image: url(/your/theme-a/img/path.png);
}
```

**style-b.css**

```
.logo {
    background-image: url(/your/theme-b/img/path.png);
}
```

The other properties I mentioned are [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) and [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) which account for the positioning you would normally do using `margin` / `padding` / `position` + `top`, `left`, `bottom` and `right` properties.

The first example shows a *main.css* title, this is purely for illustration, you could have *style-a.css* and *style-b.css* obviously have other different styles for the logo as well as just excluding the example *main.css* file entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation